# CMV Search widget url query string

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, query-layer, url

I am migrating my Flex eSearch widget to the CMV Search widget.  I need to be able to pass a query through an url within the widget.  Currently my widget has 8 URLs that are in the widget.
Flex Code:

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the Flex code. I assume you are asking about my [Search widget](https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets#search) Below is what I do to run a query from the url with my widget.

You need to include some additional modules at the top of your viewer.js file:

```
define([
    ...
    'dojo/io-query',
    'dojo/topic'

], function (... ioQuery, topic) {
```

Include this `queryString` widget in the widgets section of viewer.js:

```
queryString: {
    include: true,
    id: 'queryString',
    type: 'invisible',
    path: 'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    options: {
        startup: function () {
            var uri = window.location.href;
            var qs = uri.substring(uri.indexOf('?') + 1, uri.length);
            var qsObj = ioQuery.queryToObject(qs);
            var id = qsObj.ID;
            if (id) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    topic.publish('searchResults/search', {
                        layerIndex: 0,
                        searchTerm: id
                    })
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note at present, searching from the url is limited to a single search term (1 field).

Comment: Yes, I am talking about your search widget.  Here is the Flex code. I have 10 URL (sorry not 8) strings that are pointing to the same field.   I included one example.  
</link>   
<link alias="Windyty Wind Map Forecasts" disablelinksifnull="true" disableinpopups="false" popuplinktype="text"> 
<![CDATA[https://www.windyty.com/{ICAOcode}]]><icon><![CDATA[assets/images/i_pws.png]]></icon>
</link>  

How should I add the query in the config/searchWidget.js file?

Comment: Should these be the same? io-query and ioQuery.  I am new to this configuration.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: If my answer did not provide enough information to resolve your question, can you provide the format of the url including the query string you are using. I can edit my answer to use the specific parameters/values you use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer to my question.  I just added an additional  tag for each URL.  I used the same url in the example for simplicity sake. 
**Windyty Wind Map Forecasts**
**Windyty Wind Map Forecasts**
**Windyty Wind Map Forecasts**
**Windyty Wind Map Forecasts**
**Windyty Wind Map Forecasts**
**Windyty Wind Map Forecasts**
'

Answer (score -1):

I figured the ioQuery question. The function did not like the "-" in the text.

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/191716/edit) your answer to include details on how you figured it out? =)

Comment: Also, you should [merge your user accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) into a single account.

Comment: I only have one account

Comment: I figured out what I did and have submitted the request to merge the two accounts into cmccullough2